# What happens to a user query while I exchange partitions in Hive?

Tags: hive, hive-partitions

What is the user experience when I exchange partitions in Apache Hive?
Is it atomic or is it discrete and consists of multiple steps like:

```
partition rename 
data copy
old partition drop
table repair
```

?

Comment: Did you enable the "lock manager" or not? (Cf. `show locks`) If yes, DDL operations take a Write lock on table/partition and Reads are blocked. If no, then it's the wild wild west with `FileNotFoundException` galore.

Comment: BTW there's no reason to copy the data files, a "mv" is sufficient -- except when one partition is on HDFS and the other on S3, of course.

Comment: And there's absolutely no reason to "repair" the tables since metadata is properly updated by the Metastore. It's only useful when a lame external process adds a directory without explicitly declaring the partition.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter How can writers block readers in Hive?

Comment: Simple. Readers call the Metastore to set a Read lock before starting the MR job, and the Metastore blocks because the Write lock says data is not in a stable state... Like in any standard DBMS.